# how to use chromium with puppeteer on google colab

Tags: puppeteer, chromium, brave

## chromium not working on google colab

Hi, I want to run puppeteer on google colab.

### running test code with `!node --trace-warnings test.js` says:

```
Command '/usr/bin/chromium-browser' requires the chromium snap to be installed. Please install it with:snap install chromium
```

### installed chromium with

```
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin

!apt install chromium-browser  # also gave same result
```

### puppeteer code

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
//varv');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser'});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://www.google.com');

  await page.screenshot({
    path: 'google.png',
    fullPage: true
  });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

### Tried

- I tried installing chromium with 'snap install chromium' it says:
  error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/chromium: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
- Tried installing snapd
- `!systemctl status snapd.service`  # snapd: unrecognized service
- `!sudo apt update && upgrade`
- `!sudo apt install snapd`
- `!which snapd`    # error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/chromium: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory

### Tried brave-browser

- installation code: https://brave.com/linux/
- executablePath: `"/opt/brave.com/brave"`
- error: `(node:42514) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /opt/brave.com/brave EACCES`
- `chmod +x /opt/brave.com/brave` # did not solve

### Tried google-chrome: **`Worked while creating this question`**

- installation code: https://brave.com/linux/
- executablePath: `"/opt/google/chrome/chrome"`

### **references**:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/168X6Zo0Yk2fzEJ7WDfY9Q_0UOEmHSrZc?usp=sharing#scrollTo=_Yf4OfPBAAPR
https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snap-d-error-cannot-communicate-with-server-connection-refused/6093/23

Answer (score -1):

To use Chromium with Puppeteer on Google Colab, you can install Puppeteer and launch Chromium using the following code:

```
!pip install puppeteer
```

Now python Code.

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

async def main():
 browser = await launch(headless=False, args=['--no-sandbox'])
 page = await browser.newPage()
 await page.goto('https://www.example.com')
 await browser.close()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Note that the headless option is set to False to launch a visible Chromium browser. The --no-sandbox argument is also added to run Chromium in a containerized environment, which is necessary when running on Google Colab.

With this code, you can launch a Chromium browser, create a new page, navigate to a URL, and close the browser, all using Puppeteer. From here, you can use the Puppeteer API to automate tasks or extract data from web pages.

Comment: Got error: RuntimeError: This event loop is already running